# Can I send email from the SMTP server in Windows 2008 from multiple domains?

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp, domain

I have a windows server 2008 instance and several public facing websites running on it.  I have a need to send emails from this server - can I use the SMTP server bundled with Windows Server 2008 to do this?  I need the emails to come from different domains (or at least appear to).  For example: noreply@domain1.com, noreply@domain2.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you set the email address you're using from the client not the server, so the Windows SMTP service won't care what domain you're using in the from address, it will only care if the host you're sending from is allowed to use it to send mail.